# What is mean removing in RGB to YCBCR transform?

Tags: image-processing, compression, pixel

Some of the research authors says that ,First of all, the mean values of the three color components R, G, and B are removed to reduce the internal
precision requirement of subsequent operations. Then, the
YCbCr transform is used to concentrate most of the image
energy into the Y component and reduce the correlation
among R, G, and B components. Therefore, the Y
component can be precisely quantified, while the Cb and Cr
components can be roughly quantified, so as to achieve the
purpose of compression without too much impact on the
quality of reconstructed images.
So can someone explain mean removing part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the mean value of the R component means finding the mean (average) value of the R component and subtracting that from each R value. So if, for example, the R values were

`204 204 192 200`

then the mean would be 200. So you would adjust the values by subtracting 200 from each, yielding

`4, 4, -8, 0`

These values are smaller in magnitude than the original numbers, so the internal precision required to represent them is less.

(nb: this only helps if the values are not uniformly distributed across the available range already. But it doesn't hurt in any event, and most real world images don't have values that are uniformly distributed across the available range).

Comment: can i also recover it during inverse transform(ycbcr to rgb)

Comment: You can add that mean value back after converting back to (the smaller magnitude) RGB values, sure. I'm guessing the authors of the papers you're reading have that mechanism in those papers, as well. Storing the mean value (in order to add it back later) along with the smaller working values requires fewer bits than storing the larger magnitude values themselves, typically.

Answer (score 0):

By removing the mean, you reduce the range of magnitudes needed.

To take an extreme example: if all pixels have the same value, whatever it is, removing the mean will convert everything to 0.

Comment: can i also recover it during inverse transform(ycbcr to rgb)

Comment: You could add it back if you knew what it was, but it is no longer available in the data to be recovered.